# In general, does "the market" prefer or dislike bottom-floor apartments/flats?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, real-estate, international

I can see both many pros and many cons of living in a bottom-floor apartment, as opposed to one on any other level/floor. I'm undecided myself, actually. However, I'm asking about what the ***general population/market*** thinks about this -- not for your personal opinions.

Is an apartment on the bottom floor considered more or less attractive than the other ones in an apartment building? Does it translate into more or less money in general when selling it?

Comment: If there was such a thing as "what the general population/market thinks about this", where do you think that information would come from other than people's opinions?  Older people prefer the bottom floor.  Many people prefer the location with the fewest number of attached units (noise from the neighbors).  And before the locusts come, the floods will get all bottom-floor apartments :->)

Comment: I've always wondered about this myself, particularly when I was looking at real estate in a major city.  Bob is right, there are a lot of factors at play.  

I looked around for data on this back in 2013, admittedly a while ago now, but I didn't find anything at the time.  There's probably a lot more out there now data-wise but even if you collected all the data you're only going to have one small piece of the puzzle (unless you really go hard on this), as Bob pointed out.  

When I bought my first real estate I paid an independent broker for an assessment of the property value.

Comment: I'll be first to admit I don't know much about this stuff, but just to be clear for your very last question --  "Does [the purchase of a bottom floor] translate into more or less money in general when selling [the bottom floor]?" -- Are not "apartments" that are "sold" called condominiums? My (limited) understanding is an purchase of this type will provide the HOA much control over the units (eg noise).  As actual apartments go I lived through the '94 Northridge quake, a bottom was crushed under an upper, now 26 years later, my knee won't handle stairs, so I'm in a bottom.

Comment: @BobBaerker Market prices could accurately reflect "the general population's opinion"

Comment: @user253751 - I agree.  If a corner unit  is more desirable and costs more than a center unit, it will sell for more later.  But if growth is constant, the nominal profitability will be larger on the higher cost unit but the percent gain will be the same.